# CodeIgniter: Cannot redirect after $this->email->send()

Tags: email, codeigniter

i have the following code which sends an email from a posted form:

```
$this->load->library('email');
$config['charset'] = 'iso-8859-1';
$config['mailtype'] = 'html';
$this->email->initialize($config);

$this->email->from('info@mysite.com', 'Scarabee');
$this->email->to('info@mysite.com');
$this->email->subject('Message via website');  
$data['msg'] = nl2br($this->input->post('msg'));
$data['msg'] .= '<br><br><b>Verstuurd door:</b><br>';
if($this->input->post('bedrijf')){
 $data['msg'] .= $this->input->post('bedrijf').'<br>';
}
$data['msg'] .= $this->input->post('naam').'<br>';
$data['msg'] .= $this->input->post('adres').' - '.$this->input->post('postcode').', '.$this->input->post('gemeente').'<br>';
$data['msg'] .= $this->input->post('tel').'<br>';
$data['msg'] .= $this->input->post('email');
$message = $this->load->view('email', $data, TRUE);
$this->email->message($message);
if($this->email->send()){
$success = 'Message has been sent';
$this->session->set_flashdata('msg', $success);
redirect('contact/'.$this->input->post('lang'));
}
else{
 show_error('Email could not be sent.'); 
}
```

Problem: the email gets sent with proper formatting (from the email view template), but the page then goes blank. For instance, if I try to echo out $message just below the $this->email->send() call, nothing shows up. Redirecting, as I’m attempting above, obviously doesn’t work either. Am I missing something? Thanks for any help…

**Update**

Traced the problem down to a function inside /system/libraries/Email.php (CI's default email library). Commenting out the code inside this function allows the mail to get sent, as well as a proper redirect:

```
protected function _set_error_message($msg, $val = '')
{
$CI =& get_instance();
$CI->lang->load('email');

if (substr($msg, 0, 5) != 'lang:' || FALSE === ($line = $CI->lang->line(substr($msg, 5))))
{
$this->_debug_msg[] = str_replace('%s', $val, $msg)."<br />";
}
else
{
$this->_debug_msg[] = str_replace('%s', $val, $line)."<br />";
}
}
```

The line that caused the error is: $CI->lang->load('email'); 
Go figure...

**UPDATE 2: SOLVED**

I had this in my controller's construct:

```
function __construct() {
 parent::__construct();
 $this->lang = $this->uri->segment(2, 'nl');
}
```

I guess there was a conflict between $this->lang and the _set_error_message function which also returns a "lang" variable (see var_dump further down).

Solution: **changed $this->lang to $this->language**, and everything's hunky dory!

Thought I'd post the answer here in case anyone else is ever losing hair with a similar problem :-)

Answer (score 1):

It's likely that an error is occurring when you attempt to send an e-mail which is then killing your script during execution. Check your apache and PHP error logs ( /var/log/apache/ ) and enable full error reporting.

Comment: Checked the error log and got this: PHP Fatal error:  Call to a member function load() on a non-object in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/sitename/system/libraries/Email.php on line 1973

Comment: It does seem as though there is something wrong with your CodeIgniter install. However, you might try loading the language helper and seeing if that fixes your problem. Before any of the code you posted, put $this->load->helper( "language" ). Also, I assume that this code is in a Controller method or some other CI subclass?

Comment: Tried loading the language helper first, didn't change anything. The code is indeed in a controller "Contact"...

Answer (score 0):

You could, for debugging purposes, try doing this:

```
...
$this->email->message($message);
$this->email->send();
redirect('contact/'.$this->input->post('lang'));
```

This should redirect you, regardless of your mail being sent or not (if you still recieve it, you can assume that the redirect would be the next thing that happens).

My own solution looks like this:

```
...
if ( $this->email->send() )
{
  log_message('debug', 'mail library sent mail');
  redirect('contact/thankyou');
  exit;
}
log_message('error', 'mail library failed to send');
show_error('E-mail could not be send');
```

Comment: I've tried both versions you mention above - both cause a blank page. However, checking the log files, I found this: **PHP Fatal error: Call to a member function load() on a non-object in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/sitename/system/libraries/Email.php on line 1973**. That line reads: $CI->lang->load('email'); So something's not right, but I haven't a clue what it is o_O

Comment: This might seem trivial, but is your CodeIgniter updated? Are you using the latest version from http://codeigniter.com ?

Comment: Yup: CI 2.1 is the latest version. I commented out the code inside the function that starts at line 1973 and guess what: mail gets sent, plus  proper redirect. I ended up overriding system/libraries/Email.php with my own version (commented out code) inside application/libraries/Email.php

Comment: It seems that something makes an error. Could you try to alter the function in the `_set_error_message` function so that you dump the two variables and make them visible? Like so: http://pastebin.com/LRercnTS - if this is a bug, I'd like to see what causes it, so it can be fixed.

Comment: Here's the var dump: `string(15) "lang:email_sent"
string(4) "mail"`

Comment: Thank you. I cannot reproduce it with a clean CI install and testing with something similar to what you posted in your question. The reason for your problem is probably more localised than what we can reproduce here. But I'm glad you sorted it out.

Comment: Ahh, I see :) Yes, the $this->lang is actually an instance of the [language library](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/language.html) which is why it makes sense with the errors you got. :)

Answer (score 0):

```
$ref2 = $this->input->server('HTTP_REFERER', TRUE);
redirect($ref);
```

By using the above code you can redirect to the current page itself
and you can set your flash message above the redirect function.